# Java asm: What may cause Frame.merge of COMPUTE FRAMES to fail (Debugging approach)?

Tags: java, debugging, java-bytecode-asm

I'm manipulating a project using java asm manipulator and a get the IndexOutOfBounds error below. Because it's in the library and the corrupted bytecode might be anywhere in this big project I'd like **a)** someone to give some insight on this merge method error(what might be the causes in general) and **b)** suggest a debug technique because I really have no idea where to look at

```
private static boolean merge(
      final SymbolTable symbolTable,
      final int sourceType,
      final int[] dstTypes,
      final int dstIndex) {
    int dstType = dstTypes[dstIndex]; <----- is -1
    if (dstType == sourceType) {
      // If the types are equal, merge(sourceType, dstType) = dstType, so there is no change.
      return false;
    }
......
```

The trace is hardly helping because most methods are library methods and the one that is mine(visitMaxs) is getting ignored by COMPUTE_FRAMES..

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1263)
    at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.merge(Frame.java:1239)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.computeAllFrames(MethodWriter.java:1617)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(MethodWriter.java:1553)
    at optimiser.visitors.CallSiteOptimiser.visitMaxs(CallSiteOptimiser.java:379)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(MethodVisitor.java:768)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2426)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1275)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:679)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
    at optimiser.JarOptimiser.optimiseAclass(JarOptimiser.java:251)
    at optimiser.JarOptimiser.access$1(JarOptimiser.java:220)
    at optimiser.JarOptimiser$paralellOpt.run(JarOptimiser.java:300)
```

Comment: It’s not “anywhere in this big project” but right in the currently processed method. The `CallSiteOptimiser` should know, which method it is currently processing.

Comment: I was referring to the projecting optimizing - i.e which of all the code that produces these modifications  is responsible for the error. But you are right, I should take a look to the project getting optimized instead even if I lack the output class

Comment: Well, when you know which method under optimization causes the problem, you can debug the transformation code easier, by just providing only the problematic code as input. Since the fail at `visitMaxs` is only the symptom, the actual problem happens somewhere earlier and limiting the input will cut down the steps to debug. I’d guess, you used a `Label` without calling `visitLabel` for it, so it has no code location and no implied frame state.